# How to get all html tags from a string and add them to an array and load them in React

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am making a blogs React Website. When a user creates a new blog the html tags they add to the blogs body are saved to a MySQL database.

I'm trying to get the blog's body from the database and add all the html tags along with their attributes and content inside an array.

This is the code for the blog's information page.

```
        <article>
          <h2>{blog[0].title}</h2>
          <p className="written-by">Written by {blog[0].author}</p>
          <div>
            <pre className="pre">{blog[0].body}</pre>
          </div>
          {Cookies.get("webToken") && (
            <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
          )}
        </article>
```

The problem with this though is that it displays the blog's body, along with the html tags and everything as a string

Example image:
[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlKAd.png)

I also tried this:

```
        <article>
          <h2>{blog[0].title}</h2>
          <p className="written-by">Written by {blog[0].author}</p>
          <div>
            <pre className="pre">
              {parser
                .parseFromString(blog[0].body, "text/html")
                .querySelector("body")}
            </pre>
          </div>
          {Cookies.get("webToken") && (
            <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
          )}
        </article>
```

But this gives me the following error:

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLBodyElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead**

Any idea what I could try?

Comment: To set InnerHTML in React you will need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute. More information can be found @ https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml, there are libraries out there that will help sanitize your data to reduce the risks involved.

Comment: @IanCraddock Any libraries you would suggest me to use?

Comment: Ideally you'd want to capture the information and save it as JSON and POST that, and then retrieve it and use that data to create the blog post.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify is one of the popular ones

Comment: @IanCraddock Everything is working! Thank you very much!